# How to check return value of a function in Lauterbach(Trace32)?

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I need to check the return value of a function from a TRACE32 script.

Reading the documentation I see a possible solution to read Program Counter(IP) register and then after executing the instruction at address where PC points to take the value from there.

Is there any other function which returns directly the value returned by a function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every function has usually a pseudo-variable called "return". You can see that in window `sYmbol.Browse.Var \\*\*\<myfunc>\*` (where *myfunc* is the name of your function)

Of any variable you can get its value with PRACTICE function `Var.VALUE(<variable>)`.

So you get the return value of function *myfunc()* with

```
GO sYmbol.EXIT(myfunc)   // go to return statement of myfunc
PRINT Var.VALUE(return)  // get the return value
```

---

If you'd like to do a module test, another approach might be interesting for you:
 So imaging you just want to call the function `int func3(int a, int b)` with random arguments (e.g. 5 and 3) and get the return value. In this case, do the following:

```
Var.NEWLOCAL \x        // create artificial variable on the PRACTICE stack
Var.Set \x=func3(5,3)  // execute func3() with arguments 5 and 3 on your CPU
PRINT Var.VALUE(\x)    // get the return value
```